# What customizable machine learning toolkits are available?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I'm looking for a machine learning toolkit that will allow me to specify custom similarity measures as well as choose my own representations for the data. Can anyone point me to any such toolkits? Preferably Python or Java. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at Weka; it is open source, Java, and mainstream

Comment: Thanks. I already knew about Weka. But it doesn't allow you to define custom similarity measures.

Comment: Well, the interface DistanceFunction is referred to in a number of classes, and some of them seem to allow arbitrary distance functions. Perhaps in your case, if Weka algorithms are not what you wanted, you may use Weka just as a framework (i.e. use its interfaces, its GUI-s, its "philosophy") to plug in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apache Mahout at http://mahout.apache.org.

Answer (score 1):

[ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) is very flexible when it comes to custom distance functions. You can plug them into almost every algorithm (e.g. DBSCAN clustering, LOF outlier detection; for some algorithms such as regular k-Means, it of course doesn't make much sense. But for DBSCAN that works very well).

See their [Tutorial on writing custom distance functions](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/DistanceFunctions).

Answer (score 0):

[lingpipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/), [OPEN NLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/projects.html), [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/), [graph expression](http://code.google.com/p/graph-expression/)